# Android : OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() called multiple times

Tags: android

I have implement `addPrimaryClipChangedListener()` in Service class.But when I copy some text then `onPrimaryClipChanged()` method is called multiple times.

output:

> ```
> RESUT:copy text
> RESUT:copy text
> RESUT:copy text
> ```

Mycode

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private ClipboardManager mCM;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mCM = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        // registerPrimaryClipChanged();

        mCM.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

               String copyText = mCM.getText().toString();
               Log.d("RESULT", copyText);           
            }

        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How to Call this method only one Time?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this problem, as there is no concrete solution. You can actually check whenever you create your overlay and if there is no data in the clipboard then you can selfstop the overlay.

`if (clipboard.getText().isEmpty()) {
      selfstop();  //make a call in the overlay service to stop itself
        }`